How to embed SVGedit 7 into browser?
I put in the code below and run the live server, but nothing is happening (empty document on live server). What to do?
I tried this in my index.html file and run the live server:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <!-- You need to include the CSS for SVGEdit somewhere in your application -->
    <link href="./svgedit-master/src/editor/svgedit.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all"></link>
  </head>

  <body>
    <!-- svgedit container can be positioned anywhere in the DOM
        but it must have a width and a height -->
    <div id="container" style="width:100%;height:100vh"></div>
  </body>
  <script type="module">
    /* You need to call the Editor and load it in the <div> */
    import Editor from './Editor.js'
    /* for available options see the file `docs/tutorials/ConfigOptions.md` */
    const svgEditor = new Editor(document.getElementById('container'))
    /* initialize the Editor */
    svgEditor.init()
    /* set the configuration */
    svgEditor.setConfig({
            allowInitialUserOverride: true,
            extensions: [],
            noDefaultExtensions: false,
            userExtensions: []
    })
  </script>
</html>

